# get a property value of an individual jena api

Tags: java, jena, owl, protege

I have my class `Alert` which contain as individual

```
Alert_1
Alert_2
Alert_3
```

and each individual has properties witch contains values 
for example

```
Alert_1 : 
      hasanalyser : analyser546
      hastime: 10
      hasdatainfo: difficult
```

I can now get all individuals but I can not get those (`hasanalyser`, `hastime` and `hasdatainfo`)  values

Here is my code and it works. How I can get what I want please?

```
owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI("file:///D:/base_connaissance.owl");

OntModel model = owlModel.getOntModel();

OWLNamedClass theAlert = owlModel.getOWLNamedClass("Alert"); 
Collection CAlerte = theAlert.getInstances(); 

int nombreAlerte =CAlerte.size(); 
String[ ] list_alerte=new String[ nombreAlerte ];
OWLIndividual[ ] idorg=(OWLIndividual[ ]) CAlerte.toArray(new OWLIndividual[ 0 ]); 
for(int j=0;j< nombreAlerte;j++){
    list_alerte[ j ]=idorg[ j ].getName();
}   

System.out.println(" le nombres des alerte est:"+nombreAlerte);
OntModel inf1 = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
for(int k=0;k< nombreAlerte;k++){
    System.out.println(" \n"+list_alerte[k]);      
}
```

Here it display my

```
Alert_1
Alert_2
Alert_3
```

How to get their properties?

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for your answer, it doesn't work yet.  I tried now to do like you said

```java
    JenaOWLModel owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI("file:///D:/base_connaissance.owl");
    OntModel model = owlModel.getOntModel(); 

    ArrayList<Resource> results = new ArrayList<Resource>();

    ExtendedIterator  individuals = model.listIndividuals();
    while (individuals.hasNext()) {
        Resource individual = (Resource) individuals.next();
        results.add(individual);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println("individual number " + i + " = " + results.get(i));//here it display my individual

      Individual ind = model.getIndividual(results.get(i).toString()); 
      Property hasTime = model.createProperty( "file:///D:/base_connaissance.owl#hasanalyser" );
      RDFNode time = ind.getPropertyValue( hasTime );
      System.out.println("property value of hasanalyser "+time);
```

At the end it displays all names of my individuals, and after each individual it display property value of `hasanalyser NULL`.

where is the problème please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT WORK NOW , i can get now all properties of all individuals thanks lot , now what it doesnt work is HOW to add an individual and add properties to this individual and insert it into my "base_connaissance.owl"  if you can help me i realy appreciate it here is the full code witch work perfectly .

```
static JenaOWLModel owlModel ;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    OntModel model;
    javax.swing.JDialog jDialog1 = new javax.swing.JDialog();       
    try{
        String ns="file:///D:/base_connaissance.owl#";
        owlModel = ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromURI("file:///D:/base_connaissance.owl");//  crée  un modele owl  a partir du ficher owl charger
        model = owlModel.getOntModel();  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jDialog1,"chargement du fichier  effectuer avec succé","Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);        

        ArrayList<Resource> results = new ArrayList<Resource>();            
        ExtendedIterator  individuals = model.listIndividuals();
        while (individuals.hasNext()) {
            Resource individual = (Resource) individuals.next();
            results.add(individual);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
        {
        Individual ind = model.getIndividual(results.get(i).toString());
        System.out.println(""+ind);
        StmtIterator it = ind.listProperties();

        while ( it.hasNext()) {
               Statement s = (Statement) it.next();    

            if (s.getObject().isLiteral()) {


                System.out.println(""+s.getLiteral().getLexicalForm().toString()+" type = "+s.getPredicate().getLocalName());

                }


            else    System.out.println(""+s.getObject().toString().substring(53)+" type = "+s.getPredicate().getLocalName());


                 }
        System.out.println("\n");
            }


    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jDialog1,
                "error",
                "Information",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear from your code how you are using Jena models.  The `OntModel` called `model` does not appear to be used, nor does the `InfModel` called `inf1`.  [`OWLIndividual`](http://protege.stanford.edu/protege/3.4/docs/api/owl/edu/stanford/smi/protegex/owl/model/OWLIndividual.html) is not a Jena class, but a Protégé one.  The question asks about using the Jena API, however, so the rest of this answer assumes that you can get the `Individual`s that you are interested in, not the `OWLIndividual`s.

Jena's `Individual`s have a method [`getPropertyValue`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html#getPropertyValue%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property%29) that returns the value of a property for the individual.  You should be able to do something like this:

```
Individual alert1 = ...;
String hasTimeURI = "...";
Property hasTime = model.createProperty( hasTimeURI );
RDFNode time = alert1.getPropertyValue( hasTime );
```

The additional code you posted is printing `null` probably because the IRI for the property is incorrect.  File-based IRIs are not very good identifiers;  URIs are supposed to be *universal* identifiers, and something that includes a file path almost certainly isn't going to be *universal*.  Without seeing your data, we cannot know what the proper IRI for the property should be.  However, if you do something like this, you should be able to get enough information to determine what the property IRI should be.

```
Individual ind = model.getIndividual(results.get(i).toString());
// Check whether ind is null.
System.out.println( "ind: "+ind );
// Iterate over all the statements that have ind as subject.
StmtIterator it = ind.ListProperties();
while ( it.hasNext() ) {
  System.out.println( it.next() );
}
```